# Matlab browser version

Tags: css, html, matlab

I am currently working on a HTML5+CSS report that needs to be displayed in MatlabR2012b internal browser. However some elements are not being displayed correctly and some at all.

Can anyone here tell me what browser and what version that matlab version has on it.

I wasn't able to find anything online and i am waiting for answers from matlab support.

From what i was able to gather some stripped down version of firefox is being used but i would need more details.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab Web uses next browsers:

> The system browser that MATLAB uses depends on your platform:
>
> On Microsoft® Windows® and Apple Macintosh platforms, MATLAB uses the default browser for your operating system.
>
> On UNIX® platforms, MATLAB uses the Mozilla Firefox browser.

But it has limited functionality:

> MATLAB Web and Help Browsers
>
> The MATLAB Web and Help browsers may not support all the features that
>   a particular Web site or HTML page uses. For example, the MATLAB Web
>   browser does not display .bmp (bitmap) image files. Instead use .gif
>   or .jpeg formats for image files in HTML pages.

Furthermore sometimes you need to downgrade your browser to work correctly at old Matlab versions. [Example](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/88861-matlab-help-not-displaying-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB's internal web browser varies from version to version and from platform to platform.

I believe that R2012b on 64-bit Win7 uses a version of Mozilla 4.0 with the Trident 4.0 rendering engine. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369289/detect-matlab-help-browser) for more details.

In no version of MATLAB does the internal browser come with any guarantees from MathWorks that it will support particular aspects of HTML or CSS (and I know from experience that many aspects are not supported). It's intended for displaying MATLAB help and documentation; if it can be used to display some user-created content, that's a bonus, but it's not guaranteed.

If you need to support specific areas of HTML and CSS, you'll almost certainly find it easier to call out to the system browser rather than using the internal one.